# Sonar Ant Task running in compatibility mode

Tags: sonarqube

I have the following ant project settings for sonar:

```
<!-- list of Sonar project related properties -->
        <property name="sonar.projectName" value="bla bla" />
        <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="com.my.project" />
        <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="7.3" />
        <property name="sonar.language" value="java" />

        <property name="sonar.modules" value="admin-api" />
        <!-- all of the sub-modules -->
        <property name="admin-api.sonar.projectName" value="admin-api" />
        <property name="admin-api.sonar.projectBaseDir" location="server/admin/admin-api"/>
        <property name="admin-api.sonar.sources" value="src" />
        <property name="admin-api.sonar.binaries" value="build" />

        <sonar:sonar xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">
            <!-- path to libraries (optional). These libraries are for example used by the Java Findbugs plugin -->
            <libraries>
                <path>
                    <fileset dir="server/third-party-jars" includes="*.jar" />
                </path>
            </libraries>
        </sonar:sonar>
```

I am getting 1 warning :

```
[sonar:sonar] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
[sonar:sonar] /!\ Sonar Ant Task running in compatibility mode: please refer to the documentation to udpate your scripts to comply with the standards.
[sonar:sonar] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
```

And also The following error:

```
The following mandatory information is missing:
  - task attribute 'key'
  - task attribute 'version'
```

I understand that there were changes migrating to the new `sonar ant task 2.0` but couldn't find any place where the changes were specified.

Also, I understand that all of the modules settings now have to be specified in the **parent** `build.xml` only and not in the sub-modules build.xml files. So why do I get the errors ? I followed the example in https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/multi-module/ant . Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the compatibility mode because you have defined "libraries" inside the "sonar:sonar" tag. Instead, you should define "sonar.libraries" outside of this tag, by joining all the JAR file paths with a comma.

Then the multi-module mechanism will work as expected.

Comment: Okay, that did solve the compatibility mode problem, I think that you should mention in the documentation what needs to be changed from the older version to the newer, otherwise, the warning message on it's own is not very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Still I get the error `You must define the following mandatory properties for 'com.my.project': sonar.sources` Do i have to define `sonar.sources` for the parent project even though i defined it for the child modules ? the parent project on it's own doesn't have any source...

Comment: Yes, for now you have to (and this value will be inherited in the modules if you don't override it). But in the next version of the Ant task, this won't be necessary any longer.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand. Parent `build.xml` has nothing in it besides definitions of the sub-modules. It has no source code so what do I put in `sonar.sources` for it ? Also, please tell me if I'm mistaken, but in the previous version I defined the module specific properties in the sub-module `build.xml` itself. Now in the new version I have to define everything in the parent module only ? Or can I still leave my module specific properties in the sub module file itself ? Thanks !

Comment: The previous version had many side effects - most notably when variables were used in Sonar properties (interpolation was not always correctly done). So for now: yes, definition must be done in the parent build.xml. There are advanced ways to improve this, feel free to open a new question so that I can answer this (it's not easy in a comment).

Comment: Okay, I asked it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921418/mandatory-properties-missing-when-migrating-to-new-2-0-ant-task-sonar Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue. In my case, the build.xml looks like belows:

```
<target depends="build" name="sonar-runner">

    <!-- Define the SonarQube properties -->
    <property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://sonar-server:9000/sonar" />
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://comp-sql-db-server/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor" />
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="XXXXXX" />
    <property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="*******" />
    <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="asdfsaf:2550" />
    <property name="sonar.projectName" value="Proj 1" />
    <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="4.0.1" />
    <property name="sonar.language" value="java" />
    <property name="sonar.profile" value="Sonar Way" />
    <property name="sonar.sources" value="src" />
    <property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="UTF-8" />


    <!-- run sonar for this project -->
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
        <!-- Update the following line, or put the "sonar-ant-task-*.jar" file 
            in your "$HOME/.ant/lib" folder -->
        <classpath path="${lib-dist}/sonar/sonar-ant-task-2.1.jar" />
    </taskdef>

    <!-- Execute Sonar -->
    <sonar:sonar />
</target>
```

This means that I have setup ant for single project but don't know why its requiring for Key and Version even its defined in properties even I didn't provide any thing inside the sonar:sonar tag.

Thanks